# Alfresco - Disable search by content

Tags: search, alfresco

How can I disable search by content in Alfresco Share 4.2.e ? what are the files I should modify ?

Thank you

Comment: What does "search by content" mean and in what way should it be disabled? What are you trying to prevent, in other words?

Comment: per example when I search for the word "test" Alfresco searches for all files that either contain this word or it's name (file name). What I want is to remove that search by content , only by file name or metadata .. thank you

Comment: In the upper right-hand corner of the Alfresco Share UI there is a search box. There is also an advanced search page. End users can enter a search in either place. Are you trying to prevent full-text search from being possible in one or both of those places?